# addition using bitwise operators

Tags: c++

so the idea of my class   is to take a string of numbers `const char* s = "123456654987"` i took each couple of number and stored them in one byte
`num[0] = 12 , num[1] = 34` and so on ..... 
this is how i did it

```
unsigned char* num;
 num = new unsigned char[ strlen(s)/2 + strlen(s)%2];
    if(strlen(s)%2 == 1)
    num[0] = s[0]-'0';
        unsigned int i;
        int j=strlen(s)%2;
        for(i=strlen(s)%2;i<strlen(s);i+=2)
        {
                        int left = s[i] - '0';
                        int right = s[i+1] - '0';
                        num[j] = left << 4 ;
                        num[j] |= right;
                        j++;
        }
```

for example s[0] = 12 is represented in memory as `00010010` not as `00000110`
but now that i'm trying to overload the += operator i didn't know how to proceed 
my best try was this but even i know that is not going to work

```
int i,sum,carry=0;
    for(i=this->size-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        sum = ((num[i]  ^ rhs.num[i])  ^ carry);
        carry = ((num[i] & rhs.num[i]) | (num[i] & carry)) | (rhs.num[i] & carry);
        num[i] = sum;
    }
```

anyhelp guys

Comment: i was thinking doing the addition 4  bits by 4 will that work ??

Comment: You might want to Google "binary coded decimal" for inspiration.

Comment: @AndyG he's already doing that by subtracting '0'. Different representation, same result.

Comment: @JohnSensebe: Whoops, missed that bit

Comment: I recommend using '.' to end sentences and capital letters to mark beginning of sentences.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do the addition one digit (4 bit) at a time because 9+9=18 and 18 won't fit in 4 bits.

x-oring multibit digits however is not the correct operation.. the correct algorithm for sum is something like

```
int carry = 0;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    if ((i & 1) == 0) {
        int x = (a[i] & 15) + (b[i] & 15) + carry;
        result[i] = (x & 15);
        carry = x > 15;
    } else {
        int x = (a[i] >> 4) + (b[i] >> 4) + carry;
        result[i] |= (x << 4);
        carry = x > 15;
    }
}
```

Working in assembler many processors supports detection of an overflow in the lower 4 bits when doing an operation and there are specific instructions to "fix" the result so that it becomes the correct two-digit binary decimal representation (e.g. x86 provides `DAA` instruction to fix the result of an addition).

Working at the C level however this machinery is not available.